# Outlook 2010 - Macro to run Quick Step then categorize

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, macros

I need a macro to first, select my Quick Step named "NTP", then categorize it as "Vacancy" before I send it.

I added the categories selection drop down to MY QAT already so I can add categories to my outgoing mail, but I send this email multiple times a day and would like to click one button.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. New members commonly mistake this for a service site where we will do the work. It is a Q&A community where specific questions are asked after you have attempted something and get stuck. Please add details of what you have tried so far, including scripts, code or formulas, and we will try to help. If you need more info about asking questions, check out ***[ask]*** in the ***[help]***.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer is that you can't run Quick Steps from VBA macros, sorry.

Comment: Thanks.  I had tried multiple things to no avail.  I thought maybe someone knew something I didn't.